# REST PUT resource with ID while having auto-generated IDs

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm implementing a REST API and I want to use PUT method to create or update a resource. The resource is identified by an ID, which can be sent by user like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "John"
}
```

The Spring Boot Rest Controller accepts the messages and uses a Spring Data Repository, which has auto-generated IDs. If a record in DB with this ID exists, it will be updated, otherwise a new one with this ID will be created. However the IDs are created by Hibernate sequence. Should I move the Hibernate sequence if user adds resource with ID 5, but the Hibernate sequence is at number 2, or is there a better way how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe not, you should separate POST/PUT API to create/update like

```
POST: /users
PUT:  /users/{user_id}

     body: {
     "name": "John",
     ...
     }
```

Comment: How should PUT behave, when it doesn't find the record to update by the user_id?

Comment: In that case, said user not exist. Once you call PUT: /users/123/ {body}. It means that you're trying to update something for user `123` but user does not exist then just return user not valid/existing

Answer (score 1):

In Hibernate, if you want to add new Entity with auto-generated ID, you SHOULD NOT pass them ID column,or if you already have entity with ID, you should set ID field to **null**.

Comment: What should then happen, when user sends PUT message with ID that doesn't exist? According to PUT specification in that case a new record should be created.

Comment: If you really want to use only PUT for that, what you could do is check is ID exist, if not, set ID to null to let hibernate create a new ID for you. If exist, just save normally. But in a way, I don't know why you would have an ID that doesn't exist yet and that scared me a little bit. That tells me that you could get ID conflicts... So you may update an entity that wasn't meant to be update.

Comment: You're right, it is a stupid idea to let the user decide the ID. I don't know what tutorial I got that from.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a query method GET:

```
GET: /users/{userId}
```

This help you to get your ID.

Regards.